# which performance is good?

Tags: javascript, android-webview

I learn about the android webview.

There is some problem.

I have a xml which has logs.

I figure out two methods.

1. using javascript read xml logs to show on webview.
2. first read xml logs on android's main code , and send the every logs to
   javascript.

I'm not sure which performances is good.

Comment: How would you read with javascript?

Comment: I did it by DOM.
Is there any better method to do it??
I just learn it recently if i have stupid thinkings, very sorry!

Comment: I'm sure your thinking is not stupid at all, I was just thinking how to do it, that's all. This problem is not really simple and not easy to measure, asking for input on a difficult issue does not make you stupid!

Comment: It's really to thank you!  :)